# What does even/odd mean in HDB3 scrambling, and how does one ascertain these values?

Tags: layer1

I am currently studying encoding techniques. The scrambling technique [HDB3](https://erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/phy-pages/hdb3.html) is introduced as follows:

> - High-Density Bipolar-3 Zeros
> - Based on bipolar-AMI
> - String of four zeros is replaced with sequences containing one or two pulses.
> - A sequence of **four consecutive zeros** is encoded using a special 'violation' bit. This bit has the same polarity as the last 1-bit that was sent using the AMI encoding rule.
> - The violation bit alternates between + and - pulses for every consecutive group of four zeros.
>   [image]

And the following example is given:

> [image]

I don't understand the even/odd stuff. What does the "parity of the +/- bits since previous V" mean, and how does one ascertain the even/odd values (that is, how can we tell if it's supposed to be "even" or "odd", as shown by the arrows) as in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of scrambling is to remove as much DC bias from the electrical signal as possible. DC prevents long links, causing noise and interfering with the use of transducers/pulse transformers for power-free data transmission.

The parity is for the number of +/- symbols, an even or odd number.

- `+-` = two +/- symbols, even parity
- `+00+` = two +/- symbols, even parity
- `-` = one symbol, odd

and so on.

Four consecutive `0000` require a 'violation bit' V that resolves the problem. "Since previous V" simply means since the last `0000` problem that required resolution.